# TestNG and running same tests with 100 data variations

Tags: xml, testng

I'm new to TestNG.
I want to make 100 tests that will exercise 100 different data sets.
The data varies such that there will be 100 different data combos.
I was thinking about making 100 data xml files, and each method would be tied to an xml data set.
Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [the section on Data Providers in the TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)? It looks like this is exactly what you need.

You don't need to make 100 tests, by the way: just make one that will receive these 100 data sets in parameters.